# CSS get text to stand still

Tags: css

I have an countdown page, that counts down the time to a specific date. Now, every time the milliseconds gets only 2 or 1 decimal, the whole text moves itself (looks like flickering). What would I need to change to get the text to stand absolutely still?

I made a GIF of how it looks.
[image]

Comment: You can align the text to left, or you can give the element a fixed width

Comment: `("00"+milliseconds).slice(-3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a width to the element containing the text using either width or min-width.  This would stop it from resizing every time the text gets shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only solution is give a fix width (max width that 3 numbers occupy) to each (minutes, seconds, mili seconds).